# Crop images like a DIV background

Tags: php, python, css

I've developed a system to be displayed on a big television, for a college, it displays current and upcoming classes. To identify where that class will be, it uses a combinataion of name + image. 
The idea is that any (allowed) user could add more classrooms with it's respective photo.

I first developed it using JQuery and PHP. The user uploads an image, which is shown on the page as a DIV background, then, the user is able to resize and move that image where it fits better

*background-position* css tag is used to move the image around, and *background-size* for the scale.
Everything works great until here, since the system was all web developed.

I had to move from HTML because of performance issues with JQuery animations (runs great on my computer, but not so great on the oldy one they want to use).
I chose pyhton to do the job.

I need to adapt those background-positon and size for python, so it won't display the whole image. For that, I decided to first process the image using PHP, cropping and resizing it. With no much luck, I'v managed to generate this using after some reading on the web.

The problem, finally;
Yet, I've still not managed to find a way to properly convert the CSS values into crop X,Y and Scale values, as they seem to behave differently.

ps.: I was going to post 4 image links explaining, but unfortunatly I can't...

---

Edit to sum up what I want to do:

Convert a CSS styled div into a JPG (or png w/e) image.
Check the link in the comments the image resizing/cropping thing I developed.

---

**Images:**

- Image being shown on the screen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAv0T.png
- User interface to adjust images: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBGzc.png
- Original image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LqjC.jpg
- Image after PHP Processing: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o23ns.png

Comment: Post the links to the images as a comment. Someone will add them to your post.

Comment: Image being shown on the screen: http://i.imgur.com/pm8r6q6.png
User interface to adjust images: http://i.imgur.com/FMhDkKQ.png
Original image: http://i.imgur.com/vv4mAFN.jpg
Image after PHP Processing: http://i.imgur.com/2L1Zsuv.png

Comment: http://www-usr.inf.ufsm.br/~jraguzzoni/photo/

Answer (score 0):

The main concept of resizing an image with css is really simple.

Imagine if you have an image of 100x50, and you want it to be rescaled down to 77 width:

```
.resize-x { width: 77px; height: auto;  }
```

the height: auto will wrap the image's height according to the width stated, no big secrets around this one here.

As for the "crop", you could fake a crop with a container with hidden overflow, and move the image around it:

```
<div class="frame">
   <img class="resize-x" src="myimg.jpg">
</div>
```

and for the css:

```
.frame {
  width: x; height: x;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

I don't know if i got your question the right way, hope it helps.

Comment: No, I want to export the resized and cropped image, since it's not HTML anymore, but python.